# Kubernetes cron job to run a query on couchbase database

Tags: kubernetes, couchbase, sql++

I require to run a N1QL query on a couchbase cluster via Kubernetes job periodically.  Can CBQ tool be used? is there any such reference implementation available?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cbq shell

OR

```
curl -v http://queryhost:8093/query/service -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"statement":"select * from default where k1 = $name&$name=1;"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eventing and run SQL++ (N1QL) via a periodic timer in the eventing service.

This can make you system more portable and eliminate dependencies outside of Couchbase.

Refer to:

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-handler-basicN1qlSelectStmt.html

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-examples-recurring-timer.html